# Terraform - AWS - API Gateway dependency conundrum

Tags: aws-api-gateway, terraform

I am trying to provision some AWS resources, specifically an API Gateway which is connected to a Lambda. I am using Terraform v0.8.8.

I have a module which provisions the Lambda and returns the lambda function ARN as an output, which I then provide as a parameter to the following API Gateway provisioning code (which is based on [the example in the TF docs](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.terraform.io%2Fdocs%2Fproviders%2Faws%2Fr%2Fapi_gateway_integration.html&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGe73tTQmJvs2WS4rAOn2RT2_ZvbA)):

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "${var.access_key}"
  secret_key = "${var.secret_key}"
  region     = "${var.region}"
}

# Variables
variable "myregion" { default = "eu-west-2" }
variable "accountId" { default = "" }
variable "lambdaArn" { default = "" }
variable "stageName" { default = "lab" }

# API Gateway
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "api" {
  name = "myapi"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "method" {
  rest_api_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id}"
  resource_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.root_resource_id}"
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "integration" {
  rest_api_id             = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id}"
  resource_id             = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.root_resource_id}"
  http_method             = "${aws_api_gateway_method.method.http_method}"
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS"
  uri                     = "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.myregion}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${var.lambdaArn}/invocations"
}

# Lambda
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw_lambda" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = "${var.lambdaArn}"
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "arn:aws:execute-api:${var.myregion}:${var.accountId}:${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id}/*/${aws_api_gateway_method.method.http_method}/resourcepath/subresourcepath"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "deployment" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id}"
  stage_name = "${var.stageName}"
}
```

When I run the above from scratch (i.e. when none of the resources exist) I get the following error:

```
Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_api_gateway_deployment.deployment: Error creating API Gateway Deployment: BadRequestException: No integration defined for method
    status code: 400, request id: 15604135-03f5-11e7-8321-f5a75dc2b0a3

Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
Instead, your Terraform state file has been partially updated with
any resources that successfully completed. Please address the error
above and apply again to incrementally change your infrastructure.
```

If I perform a 2nd TF application it consistently applies successfully, but every time I destroy I then receive the above error upon the first application.

This caused me to wonder if there's a dependency that I need to explicitly declare somewhere, I discovered [#7486](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fhashicorp%2Fterraform%2Fissues%2F7486&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGulxesJzd41DPaUbds-ux1u0D8yw), which describes a similar pattern (although relating to an `aws_api_gateway_integration_response` rather than an `aws_api_gateway_deployment`). I tried manually adding an explicit dependency from the `aws_api_gateway_deployment` to the `aws_api_gateway_integration` but this had no effect.

Grateful for any thoughts, including whether this may indeed be a TF bug in which case I will raise it in the issue tracker. I thought I'd check with the community before doing so in case I'm missing something obvious.

Many thanks,

Edd

P.S. I've asked [this question on the Terraform user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/terraform-tool/PEklOCE6MAs) but this seems to get very little in the way of responses, I'm yet to figure out the cause of the issue hence now asking here.

Comment: What version of terraform are you using?

Comment: Hey, @user3610360 - I'm using v0.8.8

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are right about the explicit dependency declaration.

Normally Terraform would be able to figure out the relationships and schedule create/update/delete operations accordingly to that - this is mostly possible because of the interpolation mechanisms under the hood (`${resource_type.ref_name.attribute}`). You can display the relationships affecting this in a graph via [`terraform graph`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/graph.html).

Unfortunately in this specific case there's no direct relationship between API Gateway Deployments and Integrations - meaning the API interface for managing API Gateway resources doesn't require you to reference integration ID or anything like that to create deployment and the `api_gateway_deployment` resource in turn doesn't require that either.

The [documentation for `aws_api_gateway_deployment`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_deployment.html) does mention this caveat at the top of the page. Admittedly the Deployment not only requires the method to exist, but integration too.

Here's how you can modify your code to get around it:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "deployment" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id}"
  stage_name = "${var.stageName}"
  depends_on = ["aws_api_gateway_method.method", "aws_api_gateway_integration.integration"]
}
```

Theoretically the `"aws_api_gateway_method.method"` is redundant since the integration already references the method in the config:

```
http_method             = "${aws_api_gateway_method.method.http_method}"
```

so it will be scheduled for creation/update prior to the integration either way, but if you were to change that to something like

```
http_method             = "GET"
```

then it would become necessary.

I have [submitted PR](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/12671) to update the docs accordingly.

Comment: Great answer, works perfectly, thanks very much both for the example code fix and the explanation @radek-simko